# Shaliach Tzibbur and shul "politics"

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader

[Shulchan Aruch O.C. 53:4-5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=158) discusses some qualifications for an ideal *shaliach tzibbur* as well as other "non-ideal" qualifications. It seems that one necessity is that the congregation prefers him and is satisfied with him.

WHat happens if the *shaliach tzibbur* has been in that shul for many years, and there is a group of "old timers" who regularly attend the shul (every Shabbat and Yom Tov when this *Shaliach tzibbur* leads the service and want to keep him. The shul board members, who have the power to vote on their staff consists primarily of people that don't attend shul regularly - perhaps once every few months - want to get rid of him.

Can the board members make this decision to fire him because according to them, he is not "preferable"? Or does the halacha follow the minority of people who regularly attend and listen to him more often? Essentially, my question focuses on whether the definition of "preferable" as mentioned in Shulchan ARuch include a definition of thiose who actually benefit from his voice by attending shul more regularly.

Comment: Is he being paid? Why is the board involved with who leads a service? I don't see what the board has to do with letting someone be Chazzan or what the congregants have to do with who gets paid.

Comment: Where I daven, they appoint Gabbaim and they decide who leads the services.

Comment: @CashCow That just pushes the question down to another layer. What about where individuals put pressure on the gabbaim to keep certain people from chosen to lead the services? e.g.: where the gabbaim themselves make political choices not governed by the congregation as a whole but by a small subset of individuals?

Comment: @DoubleAA The shat"z is paid. But, I'm not sure how that fact might change the halacha.

Comment: @DanF I don't see why it would either. The board can stop paying him, but I don't know how they can stop him from being Chazzan if the people want him. I'm not sure why you seem to think they can.